# PHP fopen file path issue

Tags: php

I've created a PHP script to create a text file. When I first started it only need to be created in the same dir as the php file. Now I need to create to create it in subfolder below the script. For some reason the script isn't working. Can anyone see an error on my part? I've read around and got no where. This is hosted on a webserver atm if that makes a difference. Script returns Internal Error 500 atm

Thanks

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['jobname'];
$area = $_GET['area']
$sunits = $_GET['s'];
$wunits = $_GET['w'];
$funits = $_GET['f'];
$vunits = $_GET['v'];
$tunits = $_GET['t'];
$junits = $_GET['j'];
$kunits = $_GET['k'];
$lunits = $_GET['l'];
$yunits = $_GET['y'];
$punits = $_GET['p'];
$t2units = $_GET['t2'];
$k2units = $_GET['k2'];
$munits = $_GET['m'];

$data =  "S: $sunits - W: $wunits - F: $funits - V: $vunits - T: $tunits - J: $junits - K: $kunits - L: $lunits - Y: $yunits - P: $punits - T2: $t2units - K2: $k2units - M: $munits";

$handle = fopen("/Jobs/$area/$filename.txt", 'x') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename); //implicitly creates file

fwrite($handle, "\n" . $data . "\n");

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Does the folder you want to write it to have permission to write files?

Comment: If you're going to vote it down at least say why....

Comment: @RichardA It has 777 permission on the script as well as the target folder

Comment: perhaps the file already exists? try 'w' mode instead of 'x'

Comment: Most people will down vote for this sentence only "For some reason the script isn't working". Post the error message and tell us what you expected the code to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Does the folder made by `$area` exist? What if the variable is random?

Comment: @RichardA The folder does exist. I have premade all folders required.

Comment: @LynHeadley I tried that already too. I have been staring at this for hours now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

issue:

$area = $_GET['area']

fix:

$area = $_GET['area'];

it seems you forgot the semi colon

Comment: I simply hate myself right now. I've been at the keyboard coding for 14 hours now and I think I need to step back for a break... Thank you for the spotting my error!

Answer (score 0):

if you need to create file under the script directory,
use

```
$handle = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) ."Jobs/$area/$filename.txt", 'x') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename); //implicitly creates file
```

if you use "/Jobs.." as filename it uses the OS absolute path to create file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you receive an error that the file/stream doesn't exist or can't be opened? If so you need to place a `.` in your `$handle` at the beginning of the file url to use the relative directory.

```
$handle = fopen("./Jobs/$area/$filename.txt", 'x') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename); //implicitly creates file
```

Comment: I was getting internal 500 due to the missing `;` and was never making it to this part of the script. But you're right I did need this also :)